# How to save the output matrices in a for loop in the same file in python and then use ridge regression

Tags: python, numpy, regression, pickle

I basically have a for loop whose output at every iteration is a 1000 dimensional array along with a vector identifier (one of [001], [010], or [100]). I want to store the array along with the corresponding vector identifier for every iteration in a file such that when I load the file, the first column is the arrays and the second column are the identifiers.

I tried storing it in a matrix (say M): and to say:

```
M=np.zeros((1000,2))
for i in range(1000):
    some operation that outputs 1x100 array X and 1x3 identifier Y
    M[i][0]=X
    M[i][1]=Y
np.save('output.txt', M)
```

something like this...

I see why the allocation doesn't work. Pickling it also returns an error. Any idea how this would get stored?

I then want to use ridge regression to find ONE matrix Wout of size 100x3 such that it best matches X.Wout=Y optimized over all 1000 data sets. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `M[i][0]` notation suggests you need to review, and practice, basic operations with numpy arrays. In an interpreter, make a small array, and practice different ways of indexing and setting values, rows and columns.  `M` as you create it stores 2 columns of numbers, not columns of arrays.

Comment: Show us, one smaller scale, the kind of `M` array that you want to create.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a list like this:

```
In [140]: M=[]
In [141]: for i in range(5):
     ...:     X = np.arange(i,i+4)
     ...:     Y = [0,1,1]
     ...:     M.append([X,Y])
     ...:     
In [142]: M
Out[142]: 
[[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), [0, 1, 1]],
 [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), [0, 1, 1]],
 [array([2, 3, 4, 5]), [0, 1, 1]],
 [array([3, 4, 5, 6]), [0, 1, 1]],
 [array([4, 5, 6, 7]), [0, 1, 1]]]
```

Which could be turned into a 2d object array:

```
In [143]: Ma=np.array(M, object)
In [144]: Ma
Out[144]: 
array([[array([0, 1, 2, 3]), [0, 1, 1]],
       [array([1, 2, 3, 4]), [0, 1, 1]],
       [array([2, 3, 4, 5]), [0, 1, 1]],
       [array([3, 4, 5, 6]), [0, 1, 1]],
       [array([4, 5, 6, 7]), [0, 1, 1]]], dtype=object)
In [145]: Ma.shape
Out[145]: (5, 2)
In [146]: Ma[:,0]
Out[146]: 
array([array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 4]), array([2, 3, 4, 5]),
       array([3, 4, 5, 6]), array([4, 5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
```